# My sidenav color isn't changing with the button (onclick)

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, background

I created a JS Script that change the background of my side menu by clicking a button but it doesn't change anything

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

   function toggle_visibility() {
      var e = document.getElementById('on');
      if(e.style.display == 'none')
         e.style.display = 'block';
      else
         e.style.display = 'none';

       var f = document.getElementById('off');
       if(f.style.display =='block')
           f.style.display = 'none';
           else
           f.style.display = 'block';

      var g = document.getElementById('sidenav');
      if(g.style.background == '#F5F5F5') {
         g.style.background = '#252525';
      }
      if(g.style.background == '#252525') {
         g.style.background = '#F5F5F5';
      }
   }
</script>
</head>
<body id='body'>
   <div id="sidenav" style="background: #F5F5F5">
<div class="btn-area" onclick="toggleNav()">&#9776</div>

<ul>

      <div class="button">
            <button onclick="changeColor(); backgroundHiding(); toggle_visibility();" class="lightbutton">
               <span id="on">Turn Off the lights</span>
               <span id="off" style="display: none">Turn On the lights</span>
            </button>
            </div>
</ul>

   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I expected it to change my background to the `id='sidenav'` but it didn't change anything...
I would appreciate if someone helps me
uwu

Comment: Is this a cut-down version of your code? At the minute you have no changeColor or backgroundHiding function defined so you'll just see errors in the console.

Comment: @Tom yes it's a cut-down version of my code, I thought it was unnecessary, but I can if you want to

Comment: Are you trying to keep it plain JS or could you use jQuery?

Comment: I thought plain JS first, but I'm new to programming and I don't really know what is jQuery @zachstarnes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can accomplish this by a little modification to your styles and the JS. Just use `g.classList.toggle('lights-on')`. Creating classes is better than inline styles as well. Make sure you give the `sidenav` the starting class of `lights-on`.

Here is the complete code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

   function toggle_visibility() {
      var e = document.getElementById('on');
      if(e.style.display == 'none')
         e.style.display = 'block';
      else
         e.style.display = 'none';

       var f = document.getElementById('off');
       if(f.style.display =='block')
           f.style.display = 'none';
           else
           f.style.display = 'block';

      var g = document.getElementById('sidenav');
      g.classList.toggle('lights-off'); //<--- here is the toggle instead of your ifs
   }

</script>
</head>
<body id='body'>
   <div id="sidenav" class="lights-on"> <!-- make sure you add this class -->
<div class="btn-area" onclick="toggleNav()">&#9776</div>

<ul>

      <div class="button">
            <button onclick="changeColor(); backgroundHiding(); toggle_visibility();" class="lightbutton">
               <span id="on">Turn Off the lights</span>
               <span id="off" style="display: none">Turn On the lights</span>
            </button>
            </div>
</ul>

   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and your stylesheet should be something like this:

```
.lights-on {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.lights-off {
  background-color: #252525;
}
```

as a side note I would suggest using consistent naming for your methods so `toggle_visibility()` should be `toggleVisibility()`.

Comment: I just decided to use your method and I wrote that: var g = document.getElementById('sidenav');
      if (g.classList == ('lights-on'))
         g.classList.toggle('lights-off');
      else
      g.classList.toggle('lights-on');
      console.log(g) and it seems to work but it doesn't want to change to "lights-off" and just disable the background of the sidenav...

Comment: @AnimenoSekai There is no need for an `if` statement when using `g.classList.toggle` also `g.classList == ('lights-on')` will always return false because `classList` is an array. You would need to use `if(g.classList.contains('lights-on'))` if you wanted to check if a class is inside the `classList` But again no need to check `toggle` will remove it if its there and add it if its not.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this if-statement inside the **toggle_visibility** function

```
if(g.style.background == '#F5F5F5')
```

**.background** doesn't refer to the color only. It can hold up to eight individual properties.

For example if you log this

```
console.log(g.style.background);
```

you will see the following string

> rgb(245, 245, 245) none repeat scroll 0% 0%

in the console.

That means the comparison `if(g.style.background == '#F5F5F5')` won't ever be true.

Furthermore as you can see from the above it returns a rgb value instead of a hex number so you need to convert the color to hex first.
There's a handy library which does the job [w3color](https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3color.js)

Here's the complete example:

```js
function toggle_visibility() {
  var e = document.getElementById('on');
  if (e.style.display == 'none')
    e.style.display = 'block';
  else
    e.style.display = 'none';

  var f = document.getElementById('off');
  if (f.style.display == 'block')
    f.style.display = 'none';
  else
    f.style.display = 'block';


  var g = document.getElementById('sidenav');

  if (w3color(g.style.backgroundColor).toHexString().toUpperCase() == '#F5F5F5') {
    g.style.backgroundColor = '#252525';
  } else
  if (w3color(g.style.backgroundColor).toHexString().toUpperCase() == '#252525') {
    g.style.backgroundColor = '#F5F5F5';
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3color.js"></script>
<div id="sidenav" style="background-color: #F5F5F5">
  <div class="btn-area" onclick="toggleNav()">&#9776</div>
  <ul>

    <div class="button">
      <button onclick="; toggle_visibility();" class="lightbutton">
               <span id="on">Turn Off the lights</span>
               <span id="off" style="display: none">Turn On the lights</span>
            </button>
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `console.log(g.style.background)` and you will see that g.style.background  returns an rgb value not an HEX value like you expect.
So your code fails here:

```
  var g = document.getElementById('sidenav');
  if(g.style.background == '#F5F5F5') {
     g.style.background = '#252525';
  }
  if(g.style.background == '#252525') {
     g.style.background = '#F5F5F5';
  }
```